# Manually running flyway in quarkus testcontainers reactive

Tags: java, junit, quarkus, flyway, testcontainers

I have a quarkus 2.3.0.RC1 project setup with reactive postgres as a connection to my database.

My test application.yml

```
quarkus:
  datasource:
      db-kind: postgresql
      jdbc: false
      username:
      password:
      reactive:
        url:
        max-size: 20
```

This should tell quarkus to spawn a testcontainer instance of postgresql.  Before that however I am running into an issue with my flyway migrations.

flyway uses jdbc and as such i had to add this class as a wrapper to allow it to run

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class RunFlyway {

  @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.reactive.url")
  String datasourceUrl;
  @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.username")
  String datasourceUsername;
  @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password")
  String datasourcePassword;

  public void runFlywayMigration(@Observes StartupEvent event) {
      Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
          .dataSource("jdbc:" + datasourceUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword).load();
      flyway.migrate();
   
  }
}
```

This however is seemingly getting my `main/resoruces/applciation.yml` content as properties, which I could ignore just fine but then I do not know how to obtain programmatically the url for the spawned postgresql instance that quarkus created through testcontainers. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was in fact with how my properties were being read

as a test, I set the main/applicaiton.yml to only run for a specific profile (eg application-live.yml). like this the test couldn't find the property, and it loaded properly and the url got injected successfully